# Why are control id's important to ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net

Some web technologies such as ASP.NET MVC and any web technology, Web Forms, including use the control's `name` attribute to identify the control in a post-back, for instance, to read posted values.

However, ASP.NET uses control `Id's` for creating control (heap object) instances in the `Page` class instance.

What else does ASP.NET use the control's `id` attribute for?

I vaguely recall there being some issue about id's of dynamically generated controls. Some conflict or some such. Or some dependency. I am not sure what.

Why are `id`'s important to ASP.NET Web Forms and how does it use them, other than to name its `Page` class' properties that represent controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control `id` values are of critical importance for dynamically created controls and merging the `ViewState` data back to these dynamically created controls. This makes it appear to the user that the page just updated, when in reality the controls were rebuilt and the `ViewState` data was sent back to the server that had the `id` and value paired together and, finally, rebound to the control for display to the user.

If you recreate the controls with different `id` values, then the `ViewState` will not properly bind to the controls and it will look to the user that the page "reset", because there changes were unable to be applied to the proper controls.

Note: The `id` value is also used for statically created controls, but in the end `id` values are the keys for `ViewState` to put the correct value into the correct control.

Comment: Thank you, Karl, again. That is very nice and was very helpful.

Comment: Now, suddenly, perhaps because of your answer, I remember a little bit more about something I dealt with in the past a few years ago. I think the challenge was that some client side javascript code needed to do something to controls (getElementById, perhaps) that were dynamically generated on the server.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - No problem, glad I could jog your memory. :-)